# Backbone - change default GET URL format

Tags: javascript, json, rest, backbone.js

**REST:**

My REST API is on the following URL:
`http://localhost/Project/index.php/rest/resource/car`

This runs a standard get request that returns all the data in the table as a JSON.
However, my REST API also has the following:

`http://localhost/Project/index.php/rest/resource/car/carId/2`.

Which when used will return only the data for the Car, with carId = 2.

**Backbone:**

```
    this.mycar.fetch({
        data: { 'carId': '1' },
        success: function () { ...
```

Running the above code in backbone will create and run a request that looks like this: `http://localhost:7070/Project/index.php/rest/resource/car?carId=1`, which is not compatible with my REST api, so how can I change it?

Edit: 
**Model and Collection:**

```
var Car = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: ROOT + 'car',
    idAttribute: 'carId'

});

var Cars = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Car,
    url: ROOT + 'car',
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data` property is the jQuery `$.ajax`'s `data` property. For `GET` requests it's used for setting query parameters.

You should update the [`.url`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-url) method/property of the model instead.

Setting it directly as a parameter:

```
this.mycar.url = 'api_entry_point/car/' + car_id;
```

**edit**: I just have noticed that you have `carId` as a resource in your url. This is a rather unconventional url. It seems this is why you have `idAttribute: 'carId'` in your model constructor. The `carId` doesn't have to be in the url. It could be:

```
http://localhost/Project/index.php/rest/resource/car/2
```

In the above url, the `2` is the model id. There is absolutely no need to have `carId` in the url. Also as resource contains more than one item, using `cars` instead of the `car` segment makes more sense.

```
http://localhost/Project/index.php/rest/resource/cars/2
```

Of course it's just a personal preference.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I already have a url in my model: `http://localhost/Project/index.php/rest/resource/car` which returns all the cars. Will this be affected by making your change?

Comment: @john Just like other JavaScript objects resetting a property's value overrides the previous value. If it already refers to the entry of all the cars, you can code: `this.mycar.url = this.mycar.url + '/' + carId`

Comment: Sorry but I'm confused, I have edited the question and added my model... `carId` is not defined in my model..

Comment: @john That's okay. The model id shouldn't be hardcoded in the model constructor. That's why you call also define the url-related properties as method. Since you have set the `urlRoot` property, you can set the model id and Backbone generates the corresponding url: `this.mycar.set('carId', '....')`

Comment: Thank you! I think I finally understood it!

Comment: @john You are welcome. There is a typoin my last comment, it should be: 'That's why you **can** ...'.

Comment: Regarding the edit: Thanks for your suggestion. My reasoning was, in the REST api, the parameters are set into a PHP array so it's in key value pairs. resource=>car tells me I'm dealing with cars, and carId =>1 tells me the Id. If I follow your method I can't read a proper array on the other end.

Answer (score 1):

In your backbone model file you can pass like this

```
url : return "http://localhost/Project/index.php/rest/resource/car/carId/=" + this.id;
```

in your backbone view you can pass like

```
this.model.id = this.id;
 this.mycar.fetch({
        success: function () {
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I already have a url in my model: `http://localhost/Project/index.php/rest/resource/car` which returns all the cars. Will this be affected by making your change?

Comment: Then you can pass in model like this
url : return "http://localhost/Project/index.php/rest/resource/car/" + this.id;

in your view if you want pass car id then do like this
this.model.id = "carid/"+this.id;
 this.mycar.fetch({
        success: function () {


if you don't want to pass then you can pass 

this.model.id=""